# How to override route in a plugin nopcommerce

Tags: plugins, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, nopcommerce

I've a route like `Admin/Vendor` in my MVC application . Without changing this route I need to point this same route to another method say `CustomAdmin/CustomVendor`.

I tried attribute routing but no luck . Is there any way to do this. My current code is given below

Original Method:

```cs
public class AdminController
{
   public ActionResult Vendor()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Custom Method:

```cs
public class CustomAdminController
{
    [Route("Admin/Vendor")]
    public ActionResult CustomVendor()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to override route in a plugin?

Comment: @Div yep I need to  override in my plugin

Comment: Okay, can you show us `RouteProvider` file of your plugin!

Comment: @Div I'm new to nop is there any specif route provider file for nop admin

Comment: No worries, yes *(but not specific file for admin)* , plugin should have `RouteProvider`(which contains your plugin all routes) file. Please refer [How to write a nopCommerce plugin](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/How+to+write+a+nopCommerce+plugin). In RouteProvider.cs file you can override a route.

Comment: I could not find `AdminController` and `Vendor` in nop defaults, where it's located

Comment: @div The code I provided is sample code. What I want is, When user clicks on the customer search tab I need to re route it to my custom controller

Comment: Okay, you've mentioned, for admin route in the question, so I've added for admin route. let me know if you want to search then i will be add for the same :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're developing a plugin. You have to add your custom route to the `RouteProvider`.

In default nopCommerce `AdminController` and `Vendor` doesn't exists, so I assume that you're trying to override vendor list method of admin.

[image]

Which looks like:

```cs
public partial class RouteProvider : IRouteProvider
{
    public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    { 
        var route = routes.MapRoute("Plugin.GroupName.PluginName.CustomVendor",
                                     "Admin/Vendor/List",
                                      new { controller = "CustomAdminController", action = "CustomVendor", orderIds = UrlParameter.Optional, area = "Admin" },
                                      new[] { "Nop.Plugin.GroupName.PluginName.Controllers" });
        route.DataTokens.Add("area", "admin");
        routes.Remove(route);
        routes.Insert(0, route);
    }
    public int Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return 100; // route priority 
        }
    }
}
```

Side Note: `GroupName` and `PluginName` should be your plugin group name and plugin name.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

On your plugin which class implements the interface `IRouteProvider`, you can easily override the route there. 
Likewise I have a class named `RouteProvider` in my plugin, So I have Implemented the `abstract` function `RegisterRoutes` and simply it can be overrided by

```
routes.MapRoute("Plugin.Promotion.Combo.SaveGeneralSettings",
                 "Admin/Vendor",
                 new { controller = "CustomAdmin", action = "CustomVendor", },
                 new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Promotion.Combo.Controllers" }
            );
```

Here `Plugin.Promotion.Combo` must be replaced by your plugin directory.And using `SaveGeneralSettings` or any things you want to use that will be your route url

Comment: did you write the portion of code inside the `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` function??

Comment: yep. but still routing to the old controller action

Comment: Directly hit on the address `Admin/Vendor` by typing through keyboard then let me know what happens without clicking via a link.